# What is the difference between es and es-419 in iOS localization?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I have been trying to implement Latin America Spanish language support and I am not supporting the Spanish variant of Spain. How do I separate these two? I thought, es is for Spain variant and es-419 for Latin America Variant. so I added es-419 but my localised string is showing up for es variant as well.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code

```
es – Spanish, as shortest ISO 639 code.
es-419 – Spanish appropriate for the Latin America and Caribbean region, using the UN M.49 region code
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about iOS localization but I think I can help clarify the problem

you see, the code `es` alone just refers to the Spanish language in general, it doesn't specify any variants.
the code for Spain variant of Spanish is `es-es`,
where the second "es" means Spain

so maybe you can see if your localised string is showing up for the `es-es` variant? if it doesn't then maybe the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce any issue.

Here's how I tested. I localized my app for English (the base) and for Spanish (Latin America), aka `"es-419"`. I have a *Localizable.strings* file, and it exists in both localizations.

So:

- if I run under English, I get my English string
- if I run under Spanish (Latin America), I get my Spanish string
- if I run under Spanish, I get my English string — and that is what I expect, as I am not localized for that dialect

So it seems to me that this works as expected. I'm not reproducing any issue as described by the OP.